# FabricJs rotate object without moving the position

Tags: fabricjs

I'm trying to set the angle to increments of 90 while keeping the position visually the same. I have it working but its really hacky. Can someone improve this code ex) without needing the switch statements. https://codesandbox.io/s/lx347ln669

Answer (score 11):

`triangle.rotate(angle);`

> Sets "angle" of an instance with centered rotation

[Rotate in farbic.js docs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#rotate)

should rotate the triangle on it's central rotation. This acts differently to 
`triangle.set('angle', 90)`
which seems to rotate based on the top left corner.

You may also find this useful if you want the user to use the default controls and 'snap to' your angles:

```
straighten(triangle);
```

> Straightens an object (rotating it from current angle to one of 0, 90, 180, 270, etc. depending on which is closer)

[Straighten in fabric.js docs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#straighten)

Comment: Just in case somebody bumped into some strange issue when on the selected object you call `obj.rotate(...)` and the action areas keen the same position despite the fact that the rotated object and it's selection have changed. In order to fix it call `obj .setCoords();` See more by link http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#setCoords  _Sets corner position coordinates based on current **angle**, width and height._

Comment: @VitaliiBratok You sir are a life saver. I've been fighting with this issue for the last 8 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `originX: 'center'` and `originY: 'center'` when you create your triangle. No need to change the origins on each rotation.

```js
var canvasEl = document.getElementById('c');
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  fill: "blue",
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  originX: "center",
  originY: "center"
});
canvas.add(triangle)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.6/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Unfortunately setting the origin to center will mean that I have to set all my objects to center. I'd prefer to keep all the objects consistently set to top/left. Is there a different approach?

Comment: Using top/left as your origin is what's causing the object to move after rotating (since that corner needs to stay stationary). I suppose you could adjust the object's position after each rotation but that's not a clean solution. What's wrong with keeping your objects as origin center?

Comment: I have a grid where the objects snap and fill nicely to the cells. Will this still be possible with the origin in the center?

Comment: Yes, you'll just need to offset your object's positions by half of the object's size on each dimension. Something like gridcoordinateX + (width * scaleX) / 2

Comment: Rotation works as expected - around the center of the object - but now resizing with mouse goes haywire.